# Akonadi server does not start

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. On 16.04 the Akonadi server does not start. I need it for running kMail my mail client. The output I get:

```
akonadictl start
```

Is:

```
starting Akonadi Server...
done.
```

And then:

```
$ Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
search paths:  ("/home/peter/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/bin", "/opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin", "/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/bin", "/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/sbin", "/bin", "/usr/games", "/usr/local/games", "/snap/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/libexec", "/usr/libexec", "/opt/mysql/libexec", "/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin", "/opt/mysql/sbin")
Found mysql_install_db:  "/usr/bin/mysql_install_db"
Found mysqlcheck:  "/usr/bin/mysqlcheck"
Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi"
arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/peter/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/peter/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/tmp/akonadi-peter.JeGtpj/mysql.socket")
stdout: ""
stderr: ""
exit code: 1
process error: "Unknown error"
terminating service threads
terminating connection threads
stopping db process
Failed to remove Unix socket
Failed to remove runtime connection config file
Application 'akonadiserver' exited normally...

Peter
```

Comment: sudo?
Reference: https://xkcd.com/149/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: *`starting Akonadi Server...`* followed by *`done`* seems to indicate it is starting. You should provide more information (when you move it to a more appropriate site).